# Installing PyObjC on Enthought python and Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, pyobjc, canopy

I want to access some of the PyObjC routines using Enthought Python 7.3-2 (32 bit, OS X 10.8.3)

When I run the enpkg installer from the command line, I get a fair way through the install and then:

Error: could not resolve "pyobjc_framework_inputmethodkit" required by "pyobjc-2.3-1.egg"

So I tried Canopy 1.0 (64 bit, OS X, still a bit flakey) using the GUI package installer and I see the same message:

Action: install pyobjc-2.3-1.egg
The package manager has encountered error
Error: could not resolve "pyobjc_framework_inputmethodkit" required by "pyobjc-2.3-1.egg"

So it appears to be generic to Enthought python.

I'm assuming it's a problem with OS X 10.8.3 but does anyone know how to install PyObjC on Enthought python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

Pyobjc is in Enthought's PyPI mirror rather than in the main Canopy/EPD repository. You can see this from the PyPI logo in package manager, or from `enpkg -s pyobc` at the command line. We are aware that our PyPI mirror is quite out of date; automating this is on our to-do list but will come after other more pressing improvements to our build and deployment system.

You should be able to install a newer version of pyobjc following these guidelines: [Installing external packages into Canopy Python](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python).

Comment: "enpkg -s pyobj" fail to find anything for me.

Comment: What is output of "which enpkg"

Comment: Normally: which enpkg -> "/Users/drf/canopy/bin/enpkg" and enpkg --version ->
"enstaller version: 4.6.5" From the Canopy terminal: which enpkg
'/Users/drf/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/enpkg' with same version, and same null result.

Comment: The former is wrong, the latter correct. The reason for the former being wrong is presumably that you have your PATH set incorrectly. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: The former seems to be what I get if I follow and use http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/canopy-cli.html#scenario-creating-an-epd-like-python-environment as a way of not making Canopy be my default python.  Neither the 'wrong' or 'right' method appears to give any results for 'enpkg -s pyobj'.

Comment: "Not making Canopy be my default environment" is *not* the use case for the article you cite. I don't know what all you've done, but I suggest that you delete all the Canopy dirs, start over with a fresh install, then when you want a command line in Canopy Python, just use Canopy's Tools / Canopy Terminal command.

Comment: It would help to understand your goals. Another common way to run Canopy User Python from a terminal window without having it be the overall default Python is to define an alias which adds it to PATH within the current shell session. (This article shows you what directory you should add (whether you do so persistently or only temporarily in one session): https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH- )

Comment: My goal was to use some code in a terminal that appears to require PyObjC.  Should 'enpkg -s pyobj' from within the Canopy Terminal give me a non-empty result?

Comment: After updating Canopy, "enpkg -s pyobj" gives me "pyobjc 2.3-1" as a result within the Canopy terminal.  Second goal was not making canopy my default python, and it is what I did by unchecking the default path-modifying selection.  On my mac I used an "alias canopy='source ~/canopy/bin/activate'"  which is indeed better as "alias canopy='source ~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate'"

Comment: @DaveX it sounds like you are all set now?